# When injecting a @SessionScoped CDI bean in another one, does they belong to the same session?

Tags: java, jsf, code-injection, cdi

I'm writing a JSF application, and I need to inject a named bean into another, for example:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class BeanA implements Serializable{
    @Inject private BeanB b;
    public void doSth(){
        b.doSth();
    }
}

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class BeanB implements Serializable{}
```

Both of them are SessionScoped, and I hope an instance of BeanA and its injected BeanB would hold a same session state.

Does it pick or create an BeanB instance randomly or select the one with same session id?Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that it would possibly pick a random one? That would only lead to broken and threadunsafe applications all over the world.

Comment: I'm really new to it... I thought the context would just treat it as an ordinary object because there's only an @Inject prepended to the field. How does the CDI implementation judge two objects are dependent?

Answer (score 1):

The operative part is that BeanB is session-scoped, so whenever you inject one (no matter how or where ('cept for @New)) it will be manged based on the current session.